# Script en sql server que permita mostrar la fecha de pedido en texto de la tabla Pedidos

Tags: sql, script

Hola necesito saber cual es la forma de implementar este script en sql he probado de esta forma pero no funciona, ya que no se como implementar getdate

```
SELECT  FechaPedido,
        GETDATE 
FROM Pedidos;
```

Comment: quieres obtener la fecha actual? la fecha almacenada en algun campo? que motor de base de datos ocupas?

Comment: Utilizo sql server 2014 de microsoft, quiero obtener la fecha almacenada en el campo

Comment: Según lo que comentas, solo deberias completar el select con el nombre del campo, onda 'Select FechaPedido from Pedidos.'

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Siempre trata de explicar mejor lo que necesitas. Un ejemplo de los datos que tenias y los que querias de salida hubiera hecho la pregunta mucho mas clara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `SELECT getdate()` es para obtener una fecha de servidor, si necesitas una fecha de un campo basta con colocar el nombre del campo en la tabla y según veo en tu consulta esta quedaría así:

```
Select FechaPedido from Pedidos
```

Si necesitas hacer la consulta con otros campos además de la fecha y necesitas implementar la función para comparar podría ser de esta manera:

```
Select OrdendePedido, getDate() from Pedidos
```

Saludos, me comentas como te va.

**EDIT**

Además, agrego información que te podría ser de utilidad dada las funciones que da y para lo que puede ayudarte:

La siguiente es una tabla que indica que valor te daría la función al implementarse

```
    SYSDATETIME()      2007-04-30 13:10:02.0474381
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()2007-04-30 13:10:02.0474381 -07:00
    SYSUTCDATETIME()   2007-04-30 20:10:02.0474381
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  2007-04-30 13:10:02.047
    GETDATE()          2007-04-30 13:10:02.047
    GETUTCDATE()       2007-04-30 20:10:02.047
```

Fuente: [Docs Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Funciono Percfectamente, Al ejecutarlo mostro la lista de pedidos con sus respectivas fechas, Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada estimado, para eso estamos!